# Jquery Drag & Drop like windows taskbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

i am intermediate jquery experience, so i need help here with an awesome interface Demo:

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/asuvq76t/4/)**

But i don't know why it isn't drag to other div's with same id's "#drophere". please make it work just like Windows Taskbar. Thanks

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#dragme" ).draggable({
      appendTo: 'body',
      containment: '#drophere'
    });
  } );
```

```css
body {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#dragme {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 100, 200, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  z-index: 999;
}
#drophere {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(200, 100, 0, 0.1);
  text-align: center;
}
.top {top:0;width: 100%;height: 50px;}
.left {left:0;width: 50px;height: 100%;}
.bottom {bottom:0;width: 100%;height: 50px;}
.right {right:0;width: 50px;height: 100%;}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="dragme">Drag me</div>
<div id="drophere" class="top">Drop it Here</div>
<div id="drophere" class="left" style="padding-top:200px;">Drop it Here & stand it like me</div>
<div id="drophere" class="bottom">Drop it Here</div>
<div id="drophere" class="right" style="padding-top:200px;">Drop it Here & stand it like me</div>
```

Comment: an id can only be on the page once. `#drophere` needs to be a class on all of those elements. but I don't know what the windows taskbar looks like so can't help you there :)

Comment: @MichaelCoker bro please make it drop-able on all div with id's #drophere, if you don't know how windows taskbar looks like forget about it, do whatever hack but make it drop-able on all #drophere Div's. Please...

Comment: @Makashif you absolutely cannot *"make it drop-able on all div with id's #drophere"* because, like Mike said, you **cannot have the same ID on more than one element**. ID's MUST be unique. You can only have one `#drophere`. You have to use a **class** for this. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Michael mentioned, id's must be unique, you'll want to use classes instead.

Also, IMHO, I'd use [.sortable()](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists) for this "snap to and fill" type behaviour, not `draggable()`. You *could* do it with `draggable()` with a bit of configuring, but sortable will work with minimal effort.

Here is a working example and a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asuvq76t/6/)

```js
 $(function() {
   $(".drophere").sortable({
     connectWith: ".drophere"
   }).disableSelection();
 });
```

```css
body {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#dragme {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 100, 200, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  z-index: 999;
}

.left #dragme, .right #dragme{
  height: 100%;
}
.drophere {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(200, 100, 0, 0.1);
  text-align: center;
  margin:0;
}

.top {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
}

.bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="top drophere">
  <li id="dragme">Drag me</li>
</ul>
<ul class="left drophere" style="padding-top:200px;"></ul>
<ul class="bottom drophere"></ul>
<ul class="right drophere" style="padding-top:200px;"></ul>
```

Comment: `sortable` for snap behavior ?

Comment: Semantically, this answer is correct. However, if for whatever reason you require multiple elements with the same id (and once again this is incorrect / I am not recommending it), you can change the sortable selector to include all ids with `*[id*=drophere]`. Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/asuvq76t/7/

Comment: @Searching for multiple drop points with a "snap to and fill" effect, `sortable()` has always done the job nicely for me

Comment: @smrubin that would be incredibly poor coding. Thats like saying "you could drive your car from the rear seat if you use a broom and a bunch of duct tape". It may be technically true, but man it's asking for trouble.

Comment: Agreed 100%. Would not recommend. But if OP is specifically asking for this, wanted to provide a way to still accomplish.

Comment: I was trying to write this with `draggable` and `droppable`. After the styles are updated (draggble element) in `drop` event, it's quite hard to get this new updated element to drop again elsewhere....as if the change in style has offset something...:(

Comment: @Searching yeah, I find draggable and droppable quite frustrating to work with honestly, there's always some odd behaviour I speed hours trying to work around.